# Making scroller of spark list visible by default

Tags: list, actionscript-3, flex4

I have a spark.components.List component on which I would like the vertival scroll to be visible by default. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this via its [scroller verticalScrollPolicy style](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Scroller.html#sparkStyleSummary).  Try this to always show the vertical scrollbar for all lists:

```
@namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";

s|List s|Scroller {
    verticalScrollPolicy: on;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. so that means I can also do: list.scroller.setStyle("verticalScrollPolicy","on");